# scala: overloaded method value exists with alternatives: string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im trying to migrate from spark 2 to spark 3 then scala 2.11 to scala 2.12.
Before, my project works without any problem, but now, I had theses errors when trying to compile.

My error is

```
overloaded method value exists with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: String)Boolean <and>
[error]   (x$1: Array[Byte])Boolean
[error]  cannot be applied to (com.soc.finance.key.StreamingKey)
[error]           if (client.exists(key)) {
[error]                           ^
```

My Function is:

```scala
def deduplicate(dStream: DStream[InRecord]): DStream[InRecord] = {
    dStream.flatMap {
      case (key, objin) =>
        RedisBaseClient.withClient { client =>
          if (client.exists(key)) {
            logger.info(s"Dropping duplicate sale-item-in key=$key")
            None
          }
          else {
            Some((key, objin))
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `InRecord`? Sounds like it's definition changed. `key` must be a `String` but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking a method with values that doesn't match with the possibles types that the method can receive by parameter.

The error message:

```scala
overloaded method value exists with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: String)Boolean <and>
[error]   (x$1: Array[Byte])Boolean
[error]  cannot be applied to (com.soc.finance.key.StreamingKey)
[error]           if (client.exists(key)) {
[error]                           ^
```

Which means, `client` has two methods `exists` where one can receive a `String` parameter and the one an `Array[String]` but you are passing a value of type `com.soc.finance.key.StreamingKey`. So, when you are doing

```scala
    dStream.flatMap {
      case (key, objin) =>
        RedisBaseClient.withClient { client => // key is of type `StreamingKey`
          if (client.exists(key)) { // <- exists can't receive a `StreamingKey` as parameter
```

checking the API Reference of [DStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/DStream.html) shows that it can receive any type parameter without any restriction. I guess `InRecord` is a Tuple from your project. Not sure if it comes from another dependency that you are upgrading and the type has been changed.